# How to check if the text in an editor has focus when developing an extension?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, vscode-keybinding

Same to [`editorTextFocus`](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/when-clause-contexts#available-contexts), but I want to check this condition when developing an extension, what's the API for that?

I've tried the following:

```js
if (window.activeTextEditor) {
  // ...
}
```

But the result is not the same as using `editorTextFocus`.

Comment: `vscode.workspace.activeTextEditor`

Comment: @rioV8 Property 'activeTextEditor' does not exist on type 'typeof workspace'.ts(2339)

Comment: what if you search the API doc for `activeTextEditor`

Comment: @rioV8 It doesn't have a method like `hasTextFocus` per my searching.

Comment: because the `activeTextEditor` HAS the focus

Comment: @rioV8 `!!activeTextEditor` and `!!editorTextFocus` aren't the same thing, I tried binding my command to `editorTextFocus` will work, but using `activeTextEditor` check won't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I've wanted something like a `getContext` API which is the corollary to [`setContext` API](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/extension-guides/command#using-a-custom-when-clause-context), in this case, I would use it like `getContext('editorTextFocus')`.

After a lot of searchings, I ended up in this [Add `getContext` command](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/pull/118722) PR, but it got rejected due to [these reasons](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/pull/118722#issuecomment-805911807), basically saying `getContext` API is not the solution for this type of issues. I guess we'll have to wait until the VSCode team come up with a better API for this, let's hope it won't take too long.